# How to prove in Lua: unpack({0,1,1})==unpack({0,0,1}) FALSE?

Tags: arrays, lua, coronasdk

Why `unpack({0,1,1})==unpack({0,0,1})` are the same?

How to compare and proof them and proof they are different in Lua?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a function call appears inside an expression, its return value is adjusted to one result.  `table.unpack({0,1,1}) == table.unpack({0,0,1})` is true because their first return value are both `0`.

To compare them, iterate the tables and compare elements instead. `table.pack` might be helpful.

---

`unpack` is now `table.unpack` since Lua 5.2